# Unknown NAs and sapply vs rbind

Tags: r, for-loop, na, sapply

Query: I produced working code for my problem, but i just brute forced my way through and would like to learn more about those "errors" i encountered along the way.

What I'm trying to do:
Write a function that reads a directory full of csvs and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file and presents it as a **dataframe**.

**Problem 1: Random NAs**

```
#part 2
complete<-function(id=1:332){
  #(1)read the files
  file_names<-list.files(path = "specdata/",pattern = ".csv",full.names = TRUE)
  a<-matrix(nrow=length(id),ncol=1)
  colnames(a)<-"nobs"
  
  #returning the data frame
  for(i in id){
    a<-rbind(a,sum(complete.cases(read.csv(file_names[i]))))
  }
  b<-cbind(id,a)
  c<-as.data.frame(b)
  c
  
}


#testing
complete(id=30:25)
```

Output:
[image]

**Query: I easily fixed this with an na.omit, but why did this happen?**

**Problem 2: setting a as a dataframe from the start.**
I tried setting a as a dataframe and producing a solution, but i couldnt produce the full data frame

```
#part 2
complete<-function(id=1:332){

  #(1)read the files
  file_names<-list.files(path = "specdata/",pattern = ".csv",full.names = TRUE)
  
  df<-data.frame()
  #returning the data frame
  for (i in id){
    complete_df<-rbind(df,sum(complete.cases(read.csv(file_names[i]))))
  } 
  
  colnames(complete_df)<-"nobs"
  complete_df
}


  #testing
complete(id=4:6)
```

My output: (it only returned id 6)
[image]

**What i tried:**
the closest answer i could find online was [How to get print function output into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778057/how-to-get-print-function-output-into-a-dataframe)
[image]

**However, i couldnt comprehend what this whole function was trying to explain, i tried looking this sapply function up but couldnt get my head over it.**

**My questions for problem #2:
(1)According to the stackoverflow, nobs probably changed at each iteration and the previous values were removed. Why did that happen, even though i used rbind and not just print?
(2)What exactly does this sapply do? How is it different from rbind? I've tried looking up the function, but i am totally lost on its meaning.**

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

complete <- function(id = 1:332) {
  
  # only read the files for id's requested in the function call
  fileNames <- paste0("specdata/", str_pad(id, width = 3, side = c("left"), pad = 0), ".csv" )
  dt <- rbindlist(lapply(fileNames, fread))
  dt[complete.cases(dt), .(nobs = .N), by = ID]

}

complete(4:6)

#    ID nobs
# 1:  4  474
# 2:  5  402
# 3:  6  228
```